# Scroll based animation with GSAP

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, css-animations, gsap

I tried to make a scroll-based animation of closing jaws and a new div appear. For this, I used GSAP with a Scroll Trigger plugin, but it hardly works on PC, and doesn't work properly on mobile. How can I create this effect properly on scroll and show another div after jaws are closed?

First of all, I've added a container with top and bottom jaws and some placeholder between. Then I've used GSAP to animate jaws on scroll with this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid hero">
<div class="container-fluid jaws-top-container">
    <div class="container-fluid jaws-bg-top">

    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid jaws-top">
        <img class="teeth-img-top" src="img/jaws-top.svg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid hero-content">

</div>
<div class="container-fluid jaws-bottom-container">

    <div class="container-fluid jaws-bottom">
    <img class="teeth-img-bottom" src="img/jaws-bottom.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid jaws-bg-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

```
    gsap.to(".jaws-top-container",
    {
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".jaws-top",
        start: "top",
        scrub: 1,
    },
    y: 500,
        scroller: ".hero"
    }
)
gsap.to(".jaws-bottom-container",
    {
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: ".jaws-top",
            start: "top top",
            scrub: 1,
        },
        y: -550,
        scroller: ".hero"
    }
)
```

But this doesn't work properly on mobile devices, and barelly works on desktop

Mine demo: https://ydesign.tech/

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @devpolo, I beg you a pardon, I've eddited the message and added code.